# How to collect money on behalf of a third party in double entry bookkeeping

Tags: accounting

I run a store where I sell products on behalf of other people. For example...

I make a sale for £100. £20 is my commission and £80 is owed to the third-party.

At some point in the future the third-party is able to withdraw the money I owe them.

Ideally I'd like to keep a liabilities account of what I owe to others.

How would I represent this using double entry bookkeeping.

(ps I'm very new to accounting so sorry if this is a bad question!)

Comment: A good search term for this is "consignment accounting", here's a site with some solid examples:  https://www.double-entry-bookkeeping.com/partnership/consignment-accounting/

Answer (score 3):

Treat the £80 as you would any other debt that needs to be repaid for the purpose of bookkeeping. You received £100 of assets and £80 of liabilities in your example transaction.